# Accessing the Gmail mailbox by bot written in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, chatbot, google-hangouts, google-chat

I am creating a Google Chat bot using Apps Script.

It has to check every x minutes my team's mailbox for some upcoming messages. I used a Gmail service to achieve this functionality.

Is there any option to that the function that is responsible for checking could be run as that certain user (eg. myteamsmalibox@gmail.com)? As for now, I got all my code working but the function is running through my own mailbox.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide what you have tried so far. Thank you

Comment: @Aerials To be honest, I didn't try any as I don't know where to start. That's why I am seeking for anything that might be helpful for me. I was thinking that it has to be related somehow with oauth, but I have no clue on how to implement it in my code or/and set up this in my GCP project.

Comment: @Aerials I've come with an idea that I can share a the apps script project with the account associated with my team's mailbox and setup the triggers to run checking functions so the owner of those triggers will be that certain account, not me. Conclusion: those triggers should be run as my team's mailbox account as it will be the owner of those triggers, am I right?